# How can I check if a key is being held down?

Tags: unity-game-engine

How can I check if any key is pressed? The `Input.GetKeyDown` function is inappropriate. For example, after holding the key, I want my character to raise the shield, and when I release the key, the character lowers the shield. Maybe I'm using `Input.GetKeyDown` incorrectly. In the `Update ()` function, I wrote the conditions `if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.LeftShift)) { Protection (); Debug.Log ("Key pressed LeftShift"); }` And when I click on LeftShift in the console, it really displays the message "Key pressed LeftShift", but when I hold down the LeftShift key, the message "Key pressed LeftShift" is displayed only 1 time.

Comment: if you want to have the continious state use GetKey() this will return true as long as the key is pressed, GetKeyDown and GetKeyUp will only return true on the frame where the key is pressed down or gets released.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Input.GetKey()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKey.html) instead of [`Input.GetKeyDown()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKeyDown.html).

### What's the difference?

[`Input.GetKeyDown()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKeyDown.html) - gets triggered once when you press a key down
[`Input.GetKey()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKey.html) - gets triggered every frame while you keep holding it down

Comment: you should also mention that GeyKey() does not trigger on the frame where the key gets pressed, on that frame only GetKeyDown gets triggered

Comment: In this particular instance, wouldn't using both `Input.GetKeyDown()` and `Input.GetKeyUp()` work better than just `Input.GetKey()`? If the shield needs to be raised/lowered on a key press/release, does holding the button down matter?